# Error with use of "fseek" and "rewind" functions

Tags: c, system, fseek

I'm in trouble with a C homework. Program's goal is to get some numbers from a text file about some buildings and by using those numbers calculating the outline of the city as corner points written in a text file, in first text file numbers are written by three tab-seberated part, first number is start coordinate, second number is height of the building and third number is width of the building. For instance "24 7 6" means that corners of the building are (24,0), (24,7), (30,7), (30,0). I started to work on this program but had some problems so I decided to make it part by part, so in the following code, I'm trying to get numbers from that text file, send them to a dynamic memory part and then print them on the screen. But when I run this code, it starts and stops with a system error and the error code is "c0000005", which caused by "fseek" or "rewind" I guess, because when I delete these functions, program works improperly but does not give an error,  where is the problem?

Buildings.txt is like this:

`24 7 4
5 7 11
26 9 7
9 5 5
3 12 4
33 9 6
37 5 7
12 9 10
273 64 3`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct building{
int start, height, width;
}BUILDING;

int main(){

FILE *buildingsptr;
char karakter;
int satir=0, i;
BUILDING *ptr;
double sum;
buildingsptr=fopen("buildings.txt","r");

while((karakter=fgetc(buildingsptr)) != EOF){

    if(karakter=='\n') satir++;     
                                            }

ptr=(BUILDING*) malloc(satir*sizeof(BUILDING));


printf("%d\n", ftell(buildingsptr));
//rewind(buildingsptr);
fseek(buildingsptr, 0L, SEEK_SET);
printf("%d\n", ftell(buildingsptr));

for(i=0; i<satir; i++){
    fscanf(buildingsptr, "%p %p %p", ptr->start, ptr->height, ptr->width);
    ptr++;
}

printf("%d %d %d", ptr->start, ptr->height, ptr->width);


getch();
return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Based on the code you're writing, the main problem is that your instructor is incompetent as a C teacher. Drop out if you can.

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger to narrow down the problem?  You might want to edit the question and add a few lines of `buildings.txt`.

Comment: Recommend check the result of `fscanf()`.  `if (fscanf(...) != 3) Oops();`

Comment: Minor: Change `char karakter;` to `int karakter;`

Comment: My teacher did nothing for us and I am trying to learn by myself and it takes days to write that kind of little codes, so I'm glad that you answer my questions. What do you mean by debugger, adding some control functions for "fscanf"s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things to consider in the question code. Here is your current issue:

Since you are reading integers from `buildings.txt`, (not pointers); Change this:

```
fscanf(buildingsptr, "%p %p %p", ptr->start, ptr->height, ptr->width);
```

to this:

```
fscanf(buildingsptr, "%d %d %d", &ptr->start, &ptr->height, &ptr->width);
```

Answer (score 0):

two things I noticed are:

1. you want to read integers `%d`, not pointers `%p`
2. you also need to provide addresses of where to store the data read by scanf

---

```
fscanf(buildingsptr, "%d %d %d", &ptr->start, &ptr->height, &ptr->width);
```

edit: one more thing. after the loop, `ptr` points to some memory **after** the values that you constructed. you need to go back to the first element before you can `printf` the values like you try to.